# MEAN Stack- Where should I store images meant for particular users?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, heroku

I am using the MEAN stack for my project. I read online that it is not advisable to store image in the database itself and hence I am not doing that.

For solving this issue, now I have set up a local server (Using express) and I am serving my static image files from there.
Now I am able to use that image by using the URLs, for example:

```
http://localhost:4200/images/a.jpg
```

I am planning to host this express app eventually by using some service like heroku.

In my main website, I am achieving authentication(Sign In and Sign Up) by using MongoDb and NodeJs.
I want the images to be shown according to the specific logged in user.

Should I store my images in folder named by username of that user, so that I can genarate the URL string accordingly and access the image by :

```
 http://localhost:4200/user1/a.jpg
```

Is the flow of my application correct? Is this the way I should be accessing the images for particular users?

I read somewhere that there would be a security issue because anyone having the url of the image can access it. I am not much concerned with security now as this a small project which is not meant for many users. But any suggestions for a way in which there won't be such a security issue would be helpful.

I am new to this and any advice would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could add amazon S3 to your stack. The API at S3 returns a UUID type URL for each POST action on a photo. Your app then inserts a tuple to MONGO , linking the photo.URL to the User.ID.   To get collection of photo for a user, u have filter expression on the mongo query that returns a set of S3 urls used as values in the UI for img.src tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could use firebase for this .
Its super easy

Over there you could just create a folder with any name ans save all the images.

In the database you could just save their firebase generated link which can easily be mapped using a user_id or something like it.